# Printing arbitrary number of columns with tabulated-list-print

Tags: elisp, tabulate

I have the following function that displays a table in a buffer.

But this handles only two columns.  How can I extend this to handle
an arbitrary number of columns?

```
(defun tlprint-alist (alist &optional outbufr keytl valtl)
  "Print an associated list via `tabulated-list-print'."

  (let*
      ( (bufr (or outbufr (get-buffer-create "*Alist2*")))
        (keytl (or keytl "Key Title"))
        (valtl (or valtl "Value Title")) )

    (with-current-buffer bufr
      (tabulated-list-mode)
      (setq buffer-read-only nil)
      (setq tabulated-list-format
             (vector (list keytl 20 t) (list valtl 20 t)))
      (setq tabulated-list-sort-key (cons keytl nil))
      (setq tabulated-list-entries
            (mapcar (lambda (dyad)
                      (list (car dyad) (cdr dyad)))
                    alist))
      (tabulated-list-init-header)
      (tabulated-list-print) )))
```